# Routes not added after running `pon` to start pptp client

Tags: networking, server, 13.10, vpn, pptp

I have setup my dev server with the pptp client and use `pon {vpn name}` to start the client. I also added the following file in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/{vpn name}` to setup some routes for me:

```
#/bin/sh

if ["${PPP_IPPARAM}" = "{vpn name}"]; then
    /sbin/route add -net 10.2.17.0/24 dev ${PPP_IFACE}
fi
```

After running `sudo pon {vpn name} dump debug nodetach` I don't see any errors in the output, but the routes not added to my routing table. I've also tried changing the file just to this:

```
#/bin/sh
/sbin/route add -net 10.2.17.0/24 dev ppp0
```

And still nothing. I have ensured that the file is owned by root and has executable permissions (755).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/bin/sh
```

should be

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and make sure the file is executable.